# how can you see what ip/mac/hostname is connected to a switch port

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, linux, packet-loss

was wondering if there is a way for me to actually see which ip/hostname/ and/or mac address is connected to a certain port of a switch.

lets say I have a 50 port switch, and a cable is going bad and/or upload download speed is going slow

- what is the best way to check if packets are being lost to a specific host
- if you can use a terminal from a linux machine to see which host or ip is      connected to a certain port on a switch (say port 8)
- if i were to go into conf t in a cisco switch, what would be the best command to display what hosts are connect to what port

Comment: You're asking three different questions all in the same post.  Most if not all of them are duplicates of questions we already answered.  Please break this into three different questions and delete this one

Comment: Configuration mode (entered with "conf t") is not the mode you'll want to be in when troubleshooting and gathering information. It's just for configuration, i.e., making changes to the switch operation. You will want to be in privileged exec mode, which has a prompt of <hostname>#.

Answer (score 1):

To check packet loss the show interface command contains a lot of information regarding errors, CRC's, and other useful information to check if any errors have occurred on the line.

On a Linux machine arp will output a list of Ethernet address their associated IP's and which interface they are on. If the switch is not a Linux device but a separate managed switch, I would suggest just remoting into the device and listing said devices mac address table

The mac table would show you all the attached devices (assuming they have sent at least one packet)
the do command will allow you to do enabled commands from conf t
ex: "do show mac address-table"
If you are looking for a specific mac address you can pipe to include

> ex: "do show mac address-table | include xxxx.xxxx.xxxx "

here xxxx.xxxx.xxxx is your desired mac address,
Example output

> Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
>
> ----    -----------       --------    -----
>
> 900    0022.90b9.xxxx    DYNAMIC     Gi0/2

In this case the cevice with the mac address 0022.90b9.xxxx is on the interface Gigabit 0/2

to check whats connected on a specific interface pipe through to include just that interface

> ex: "do show mac address-table | include Gi0/1"

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am looking for the "port" that a workstation is connected to.  I already have the mac, ip, and hostname. Just what port is the device on? Example, I have a cisco switch with 50 ports. How would I find the port number it is on

Comment: port is one of the fields in the mac address-table. As per mikes previous comment on your question, possibly break this question up and look for previously answered question pertaining to each. Mean while I will update my answer to highlight the fact that show mac includes the port